# What is the maximum number of hybrid orbitals an atom can have?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, hybridization

What is the maximum number of hybrid orbitals and atom can have? It is usually seen that an atom does not have more than 6 hybrid orbitals. Why is it so?

Comment: What about hydrated salts of lanthanides? For example, $\ce{[Eu(H2O)9]^{3+},[ReH9]^{2-}}$

Answer (score 2):

The number 6 relates to a central atom in a molecule with octahedral geometry such as [sulfur hexafluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_hexafluoride). $\ce{SF6}$

[image]

(image from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_hexafluoride#/media/File:Sulfur-hexafluoride-2D-dimensions.png))

A central atom with 8 other atoms does occur in ionic crystals (body centered cubic), but not in any molecules to my knowledge (memory...).

[image]

(image from [website location](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-fb4b2b28179221c6b4391efaa99909a4.webp))